# FIR filter design with flat passband but equi-ripple stop-band

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter

I am looking for a lowpass FIR filter with flat passband but equi-ripple stopband. In other words, it likes [Chebyshev_filter Type II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter) except that it is FIR instead of IIR. Linear-phase is preferred.

Thanks

Comment: Provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you the Parks-McClellan method. In Matlab you can use $\tt{firpm}$.

Matlab's (now obsolete function) $\tt{remez}$ also uses this scheme.

The FIR filter is optimally designed to approximate e.g. a Chebyshev filter such that the maximum error between the filter's response and the desired response is minimized.

For more information see [this](https://au.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firpm.html) and the examples therein.

Comment: Parks-McClellan gives minmax approximation. The generated FIR has equi-ripple at both passband and stopband. It is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Not really. Examples are [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ecjc.1148/abstract) and [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6952219/) (and more you can find by just a quick search).

Comment: BTW, you might also find [this](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/pubs/ExchangeTCAS.pdf) useful. It also uses a modified version of Parks-McClellan.